# SharePoint Approval Workflow using Task process in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on a Approval workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 using Tasks Lists. There are multiple approvers and each one should approve the request for the request to be approved. But the rejection criteria is that if anyone of them rejects, the request should be rejected. If I select "Completion Criteria" as Wait for all responses in Task process action, it works fine absolutely for Approval. But it is not fulfilling the rejection criteria as this returns the outcome that received the most number of responses.  Is it possible to achieve the rejection criteria using Task process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should select `Wait for specific response` as `Completion Criteria` option.
Specify `Rejected` as the `Required Outcome`.